# install security updates without destroying cuda

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, security, cuda

I need to find a good way how to install Ubuntu (e.g. 18.04) security updates without destroying my Nvidia / CUDA configuration.

Here is what usually happens

- I need to use CUDA in very specific versions for machine learning
- therefore I install CUDA by directly downloading and executing the ".run"-file from Nvidia's website
- now when I simply install Ubuntu security updates my Nvidia drivers and CUDA stop working

The reason seems to be that while updating Ubuntu, all kind of libraries that were suppressed by Nvidia / CUDA get overridden by the update. Some of the culprits seem to be anything that has

- mesa (open source graphics driver?)
- nouveau (open source graphics driver?)
- kernel  (Ubuntu's core libraries?)

in its name.
I could now go ahead and just check off those entries and go ahead with the installation, but since I've been burned so many times by doing these updates, I would like to know if there is a "best practice" how to do this?

PS: Some of the problems that occurr when simply updating everything

- Ubuntu login loop
- black screen on reboot
- having to reinstall Nvidia / Cuda
- having to reinstall Ubuntu (!)
- having to switch back to old / specific kernel while booting otherwise CUDA won't work

(I encountered all of them on various occasions all in the context of Ubuntu Update)

Comment: If you didn't install Nvidia drivers and Cuda from the official Ubuntu repositories as should have and instead used Nvdia's binaries then obviously you need to repeat the process for each and every kernel update.

Comment: As mentioned above: I need very specific versions of cuda, i.e. I also to be able to switch back and forth between versions without reinstalling them. It's because in order to work with different code bases I need to work with tensorflow and pytorch in different versions. Each version can have special CUDA / CUDNN requirerments which I'm handling by switching symlinks (eg /local/usr/cuda ) in order to point to the required version. Every new CUDA version also comes with it's own new Nvidia driver. Therefore I have to install Nvidia drivers and CUDA via ".run" files